# Redis - Loading Dataset is Memory Sport:

Tags: redis, servicestack.redis

We are using Redis for Windows and ServiceStack as client library. We are getting the following memory issue from the Redis storage. It was able recover immediately but still this issue is causing some unexpected behaviour in the application .

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Loading dataset error message happens in two cases:

1. At master startup.
2. When a slave reconnects and performs a full resynchronization with a master.

The app should be able to deal with it, and retry a query or handle the failure in a graceful way.